# Get all role names of a cube in say a string array

Tags: c#, permissions, ssas, roles, olap-cube

With help of AMO (Application Management Objects) was able to find a solution to clear members of a particular role in a cube with c# code. 
Simple code i used was :

```
Role role = new Role();
role = db.Roles.FindByName("roleName1");
role.Members.Clear();
role.Update()
```

Now i seem to have a situation. I do not know before hand the roleName parameter that i pass in "FindByName" function..
I do not know RoleName before.
Any kind of idea so as to how to get role names for a cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finallyy :)

```
foreach (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Role CubeDbRole in db.Roles)
{
string Rolename = CubeDbRole.Name;
MessageBox.Show(Rolename);
CubeDbRole.Members.Clear();
CubeDbRole.Update();
foreach (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.RoleMember CubeRoleMember in CubeDbRole.Members)
{
//In case you want to display members
 MessageBox.Show(CubeRoleMember);
    } 
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
foreach(Role role in db.Roles) {
    if(<some condition, possibly using properties like role.Name>) {
        role.Members.Clear();
        role.Update();
    }
}
```

You can find the properties and methods of the `Role` class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.role.aspx.